# Close all open forms except the main menu in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Trying to close all forms except for the main menu using

```
FormCollection formsList = Application.OpenForms;
```

with a foreach loop and saying,

```
if (thisForm.Name != "Menu") thisForm.Close();
```

Which works ok, it skips the menu, and closes the first, but it then errors:

> Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

and stops. I have tried a few places, and they all say that this foreach loop is the way to do it, and it is especially annoying as I am not updating my forms list after closing the forms, which I thought might work. The only thing I could think of was to start at the back and work forward using a while.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If you use foreach to enumerate through a collection, it can't be modified (items added or removed) during the iteration.  Try copying references to the forms to another collection, and then remove them by iterating through that collection.

In situations like this, you can use a list or a simple array, such as:

```
List<Form> openForms = new List<Form>();

foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
    openForms.Add(f);

foreach (Form f in openForms)
{
    if (f.Name != "Menu")
        f.Close();
}
```

Or you can use a for loop:

```
for (int i = Application.OpenForms.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (Application.OpenForms[i].Name != "Menu")
        Application.OpenForms[i].Close();
}
```

Or, my new and current favorite, you can use the Reverse() method:

```
foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms.Reverse())
{
    if (f.Name != "Menu")
        f.Close();
}
```

Comment: Note to others - Reverse does not appear to be available in .NET framework 4.

Comment: This will not close the form if any Dialog (FileBrowser or MessageBox with YesNo buttons) is open, which requires user interaction. How to close that forms?

Answer (score 4):

Here's an even more concise method that uses the same number of lines as your original method:

```
Form[] forms = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().ToArray();
foreach (Form thisForm in forms)
{
    if (thisForm.Name != "Menu") thisForm.Close();
}
```

By using Linq's extension method `Cast`, you can avoid looping through the collection to build an array.

Comment: I used this for my problem ...

Answer (score 2):

That happens when the collection is changed inside a foreach loop that uses it. You are removing an item from `formsList` inside the loop.

Try this:

```
for (int i = formsList.Count-1; i > 0; i--)
{
    if (formsList[i].Name != "Menu")
    {
        formsList[i].Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To Close all forms :

```
        for (int i = Application.OpenForms.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (Application.OpenForms[i].Name != "Menu")
                Application.OpenForms[i].Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I needed to perform this same scenario and came up with a elegant and simple way to achieve this as follows

```
        Form[] formsList = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().Where(x => x.Name == "Form1").ToArray();
        foreach (Form openForm in formsList)
        {                
            openForm.Close();
        }
```

This will close ALL windows that where opened called Form1

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, you can't modify a collection in its foreach.

Instead, you can use a backwards `for` loop.

Comment: I am trying to close all open forms. When I close first form.. Application.OpenForms FormCollection changes and it throws me exception when it trys to close next form inside for loop

Answer (score 0):

as the form collection is updating for every iteration.  When you close a form, it is removed from the form collection. it's like removing a object from memory while it is using .