# Close specific form by its name

Tags: c#, winforms

I've searched a bit, and I can only find solutions to loop through FormCollection and close forms. However, I want to close a single form specificly (if its open). Do anyone know how achieve something like this?

```
if(Form.Name("myForm") == open)
    close(Form.Name("myForm"));
```

Comment: How about making sure you have a reference to it to begin with? Ie. when you construct it, store a reference to it somewhere. Also, when looping through the FormCollection, do you find your form there? If so, then what is the problem?

Comment: I didn't tried it works or not but from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9029389/447156) `foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms) { if (f.Name == "myForm") f.Close(); }`

Comment: well, its not certain this form even exists. So I want to check if it is an open instance of this form - by its name. And if it is, close it.

Comment: @SonerGönül thx, that codes gives a "An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll". Like its been "edited"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you close a form `Application.OpenForms` ***changes***, that's why you have to close in ***two steps***:

```
  List<Form> forms = new List<Form>();

  // All opened myForm instances
  foreach(Form f in Application.OpenForms)
    if (f.Name == "myForm")
      forms.Add(f);

  // Now let's close opened myForm instances
  foreach (Form f in forms)
    f.Close();
```

Or in more concise implementation using *Linq*:

```
   Application.OpenForms
     .OfType<Form>()
     .Where(form => String.Equals(form.Name, "myForm"))
     .ToList()
     .ForEach(form => form.Close());
```

Comment: A solid set of approaches.  Although, unless you are already familiar with Linq, I suspect the former is more readable, and therefore, more _concise_ than the latter.

Comment: I dont get any of these two work. In the non Linq version, I added a '=' in the ifstatement. Didnt get it to work though :(

Comment: Can it have something to do with my initation of the forms? I type them like this FormClass var = new FormClass(); var.ShowDialog(this);

Comment: Please help me, I'll accept this. I just need it to work. Is my initiation correct? As I wrote above?

Comment: @user3427831: Yes, you're quite right, it should be `==` instead of `=`; I'm sorry fo the typo.

Comment: Is my initiation correct? What the "this" in .ShowDialog(this) do?

Comment: We put just .ShowDialog(); ShowDialog(this) is very rare case when you work with Windows Handles, unsafe windows etc. `FormClass var = new FormClass(); var.ShowDialog();`

Answer (score -1):

You can also do `FORMNAMEHERE.ActiveForm.Close();`

Comment: OP's problem is having the *name* of the target form as a string. Your code *hardcoded* the target form instead, and actually hold a direct reference, no need to find them in that case, and you'd have to write yet another line for each form