# Close multiple but specified forms (exclude main form)

Tags: c#, forms

Please, I want to close multiple but specific forms (excluding main form) from a form with button click event. I have tried the following code but closes all forms (though, excluding main form).

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;
      if (fc.Count > 1)
          {
             for (int i = (fc.Count); i > 1; i--)
              {
                 Form SelectedForm = Application.OpenForms[i - 1];
                 SelectedForm.Close();
              }
          }
 }
```

The forms I would like to close are form2, form3, form5, form7, form12, form16, form17, form18, form19, form21, form22, form22, form23, form24, form25. Would appreciate any valuable assistance. Thank you.

Comment: Is `form2` a form name? You can [close form by name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23054410/1997232). You can specify array of forms to search and close. Perhaps a better idea would be to give your controls proper names (e.g. `formLogin` and `buttonCloseAllReports`) and implementing certain interface (e.g. `IReportForm`) to distinguish which forms should be closed by `buttonCloseAllReports`.

Comment: just specifying the forms to be closed. i will manipulate given code.

Comment: Is there anything common between all those forms? What `button1` is actually doing?

Comment: Button 1 closes all the forms as specified

Comment: Ok, why `form20` is not specified?

Comment: Not required...

Comment: Ok, I gave up. It doesn't looks like you *"Would appreciate any valuable assistance"*

Comment: The idea is to close the specified forms on button click

Comment: I don't get you, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a parent form and others will inherit from it and those who inherited from this form will be closed when necessary

**1. create Parent Form**

```
public partial class MyParentForm : Form
{
   public MyParentForm()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
   }
}
```

**2. Create a test form by inheriting from MyParentForm**

```
public partial class TestForm : MyParentForm
{
   public TestForm()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
   }
}
```

**3. Close forms inherited from MyParentForm**

```
FormCollection fc = Application.OpenForms;
for (int i = (fc.Count); i > 1; i--)
   if (Application.OpenForms[i - 1] is MyParentForm)
      Application.OpenForms[i - 1].Close();
```